# SPF Not Being Recognized

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, spf

I'm working on setting up a VPS on Vultr (Ubuntu 14.04). The hostname is setup on the server as `host2.sethta.com`.

I've almost got everything setup how I want, but Google is rejecting emails from the server, complaining about the lack of an SPF.

I originally created the SPF record for `host2` with `v=spf1 a -all`, but I couldn't get it to go through. I then changed the SPF record to a wildcard.

Running nslookup on a fake subdomain, I get a response of `wildcardtest.sethta.com  text = "v=spf1 a -all"`, so I know the wildcard is working. But when I run it for `host2`, I get a response of `*** Can't find host2.sethta.com: No answer`.

What am I missing?

**Update:**
The main question is referring to why a SPF record isn't being recognized.

The SPF is not being recognized, and it appears to be a setting from my server. [Using this testing tool](http://vamsoft.com/support/tools/spf-policy-tester) and entering in the IP address `45.63.69.14` *(I'm not really worried about security right now as I plan on removing the server)* and the sender address as `www-data@host2.sethta.com`, I get the response: No SPF policy was found in (no TXT record). But when I test it with `www-data@host1.sethta.com`, I get a passing SPF record.

This led me to remove the A record for `host2.sethta.com` and create a new record for `host1.sethta.com`. Now that everything has propagated, `host1` fails with a SPF lookup and `host2` passes.

I'm going to send a support ticket to Vultr and see if they have ever had an issue with their servers doing this.

Or is there a server setting that can block SPF lookups?

Comment: Why are you putting the SPF record on a wildcard subdomain, rather than on the domain that is sending the mail?

Comment: As mentioned, I already tried that, so I put it on the wildcard just to make sure it was working. Because it works for the wildcard, it should apply to the host, but it's not. Is there some setting I need to add to the host, or something that could possibly be blocking the SPF record from working?

Comment: You'll need to define exactly what "doesn't work".  You've got all sorts of confusion going on here.  The CNAME on `sethta.com` probably isn't helping anything.

Comment: Ok. I've been trying a lot of different things, so who knows what you saw when you checked. Thankfully, I have my DNS settings set to 5 min for all of this testing. I've updated the question with more information. I'll modify the CNAME on `sethta.com` to the same A record as the server.

Comment: So I'm still not sure what the issue is. I decided to rebuild the server and now it's all working, so it must have been a weird server configuration. Good news is that it's working now.